# How to identify programmatically which connection is active (WiFi or Ethernet) in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a requirement to identify, which connection is active (WiFi or Ethernet) in Iphone programmatically. If, user is using WiFi then I have to display different view controllers in my app.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use apple provided Reachability class hear bellow example please check this sample code who provide by apple.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html

you can use it in your Project like bellow steps:-

`included Apple's Reachability.h & .m from their Reachability example.`

`add the SystemConfiguration framework.`

when u use it you just called Bellow method:-

```
Reachability* wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"] retain];
NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

switch (remoteHostStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Access Not Available");
        break;
    }

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WWAN");
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable WiFi");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example is very much suitable for my app

Comment: Hi @Nitin Gohel, could we able to test this in Simulator

Comment: yes ofcource you can test in simulator. first test with wifi on and put breck point on particular method. then off wifi and test it

Comment: where can we find WiFi turn off option in simulator

Comment: simulatore test via mac internate connection you just need to turn of mac system wifi connect my frnd

Comment: this example gives host is rechable through Wifi or not. But, I want whether users activated WiFi in his phone or not. How can I know wifi on or off directly.

Comment: i am not getting you what you trying as par your task you need to just check its wifi available or not and while iphone wifi activated you got log you using wifi at rechability class

Comment: I don't want to use 'reachabilityWithHostName', because If WiFi I have to call a webservice for every 30 sec and if not then I have to call webservice for every 60 sec. So, On loading view I want to detect WiFi on/off irrespective of server hostname

Comment: check this http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7300-test-if-internet-connection-available.html